# Building Android Studio Project with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build my Android Studio project using Gradle, and to be Honest I'm not really sure what i'm doing!

Here is how I am set up:

**build.gradle (in my Facebook Module)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (in my main Module)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'FriendProject\\libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'FriendProject\\src\\main\\AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['FriendProject\\src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['FriendProject\\src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['FriendProject\\src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['FriendProject\\src']
            res.srcDirs = ['FriendProject\\src\\main\\res', 'FriendProject\\src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['FriendProject\\assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('FriendProject\\build-types\\debug')
        release.setRoot('FriendProject\\build-types\\release')
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle (in main module)**

```
include ':libraries:facebook', ':FriendProject'
```

Now, in the command line I type:

```
gradle packageDebug
```

and I get a whole load of errors, but all in this format:

```
  symbol:   variable id
  location: class R
  error: cannot find symbol
_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                                        ^
```

If anyone could help I would appreciate it. I'm not familiar with any of this at all, but if you require more information, I can provide. Thanks

*(Also as a side question, how do I get Gradle to work inside Android Studio?, it says I need to migrate my project, but do not know how to do this. Thanks again!)*

**EDIT: **

If needed, I have the directory tree of my project here:

```
+---FriendProject
|   +---build
|   |   \---manifests
|   |       \---debug
|   +---libs
|   +---resarwae
|   |   +---manifests
|   |   |   \---debug
|   |   |       \---gen
|   |   |           \---com
|   |   |               \---Marsh
|   |   |                   \---friendproject
|   |   \---source
|   |       +---buildConfig
|   |       \---r
|   \---src
|       \---main
|           +---gen
|           |   \---com
|           |       \---Marsh
|           |           \---friendproject
|           +---java
|           |   \---com
|           |       \---Marsh
|           |           \---friendproject
|           |               +---Activities
|           |               +---AdapterDetails
|           |               +---Adapters
|           |               +---Base
|           |               +---Fragments
|           |               +---Miscellaneous
|           |               +---Utilities
|           |               \---Views
|           \---res
|               +---drawable
|               +---drawable-hdpi
|               +---drawable-mdpi
|               +---drawable-xhdpi
|               +---drawable-xxhdpi
|               +---layout
|               +---menu
|               +---values
|               +---values-sw600dp
|               +---values-sw720dp-land
|               +---values-v11
|               +---values-v14
|               \---xml
+---gradle
|   \---wrapper
+---libraries
|   \---facebook
|       +---gen
|       |   \---com
|       |       \---facebook
|       |           \---android
|       +---libs
|       +---res
|       |   +---drawable
|       |   +---drawable-hdpi
|       |   +---drawable-ldpi
|       |   +---drawable-mdpi
|       |   +---drawable-xhdpi
|       |   +---layout
|       |   +---values
|       |   +---values-es
|       |   +---values-hdpi
|       |   +---values-he
|       |   +---values-iw
|       |   +---values-ldpi
|       |   +---values-mdpi
|       |   \---values-xhdpi
|       +---src
|       |   \---com
|       |       \---facebook
|       |           +---android
|       |           +---internal
|       |           +---model
|       |           \---widget
|       +---TestApp
|       |   +---res
|       |   |   +---drawable-hdpi
|       |   |   +---drawable-ldpi
|       |   |   +---drawable-mdpi
|       |   |   +---layout
|       |   |   \---values
|       |   \---src
|       |       \---com
|       |           \---facebook
|       |               \---sdk
|       \---tests
|           +---assets
|           +---res
|           |   +---layout
|           |   \---values
|           \---src
|               \---com
|                   \---facebook
|                       +---internal
|                       +---model
|                       \---widget
```

Answer (score 0):

If the message says that your poject uses an old version of Gradle then you should change all the lines `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6+'` or whatever version you want to use and rebuild your project.

If you want to ugrade the Gradle version your Android Studio is using then you can modify the file "gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties" in your project directory. It should look like this (on Linux):

```
#
#Thu Jul 18 15:45:25 CEST 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip
```

and change the distributionUrl to the version you want to use. Then close your project and reopen it, Android Studio should download and use the new gradle version.

Comment: Also change 

    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

with compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0' //or 19 with last sdk, and remove android-support-v4.jar from libs folder